# Bootstrap - Load modal residing in other page and form submission from modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

1.I've a page where on clicking button brings up the modal. What I would like do to is move all models to a separate page. I've tried this

```
    $('#newSection').click(function(){
        $('#temp').load('adminmodels.php');
        $('#newSectionModal').modal('show');
    });
```

On first click, nothing happens. On subsequent clicks, the modal appears and fades automatically. Please suggest and corret my code.

2.I would like to submit a form from inside of a modal and then display the response in the modal itself.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#user_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('disabled',true);
            $.post('__admin_ajax.php',postString,function(response){
                $('#user-modal-body').html(response);
            });
        });
    });
```

The response of previous form submission retained for subsequent modal loads.

Answer (score 0):

I find for this type of logic, it's easier to just use an iframe.

```
<div id="newSectionModal">
  <iframe id="modal_frame"/>
<div>
```

And then in the code.

```
$('#newSection').click(function(){
    $('#modal_frame').attr('src', 'adminmodels.php');
    $('#newSectionModal').modal('show');
});
```

Because it's in a frame, you can handle the form submission as if it were in it's own window. At any time, you can trigger the parent frame by calling window.parent. Ex: window.parent.trigger("form-submitted")